# Как создать графику для морского боя c++

Tags: c++

Ребят, нужна помощь. МЫ собрались командой, чтобы написать на c++ морской бой. С меня требуется сделать простую 2d графику. Как это сделать? нет ни малейшего предположения

Comment: Гуглить не пробовали? В интернете куча информации.

Comment: Давай подумаем, если спрашиваю. Наверное же не нашёл. К чему эти "УМНЫЕ" предложения?

Comment: DirectX, OpenGL, SDL - примеры графических библиотек. Хотя для "Морского боя", полагаю, и обычный GDI подойдёт (если писать под Windows).

Comment: @dimayolo очень плохо искали. Вы можете написать в гугле "Простая 2d графика на c++" и увидеть кучу похожих вопросов. А если написать "2д движок на c++" можно вообще целую статью найти и самому простой движок написать. [ссылка](https://proglib.io/p/cpp-game-engine). Первая ссылка в гугле. И да спасибо что оценили мои два предложения, как "умные".

Answer (score 1):

Если работать в винде - то хорошим началом может быть GDI+. Она (графическая библиотека) довольно простая: кисти, фигуры и т.п.

Можно взять книжку Страуструпа "Язык программирования С++. Краткий курс" - там в главе 4 ("Классы") есть пример того, как может выглядеть графическая библиотека. Таким образом, Вы бы убили двух зайцев: освоили кусок классической книжки и написали графику для игры.

Если Вы в вопросе напишете, под какую OS вы разрабатываете игру, и это окажется Windows -  я могу добавить в ответ пример GDI+ - ного кода, хотя, вообще, таких примеров реально множество.

Под Linux ничегопосоветовать не могу, работал там только с псевдографикой при помощи ncurses.

И еще одно замечение: мы тут все взрослые люди, и, конечно же,  никто никого не учит "как надо себя вести". Но, по негативному тону комментариев к Вашему вопросу, Вы можете догадаться, что вопрос написан так, что люди на него... как то злятся. Почему? наверное, можно глянуть раздел о том, [как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Не помешало бы - написать OS, чтобы в комментариях не гадали и  не давали Вам неприменимых советов, написать, что Вы сами делали и что не получилось. Скорее всего, тогда отношение к Вашему вопросу будет позитивным. А то ведь - закроют, а кому от этого будет хорошо?